# toChar is not a value of Unit

Tags: scala

```
for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- 0 until str.length) {
    print(c + i).toChar
}

for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- 0 until str.length) yield (str(c) + i).toChar
```

When I run the first code snippet above I get the error: `value toChar is not a member of Unit`. But when I run the second code snippet with yield the error goes away.

Is this because the `statement print(c+i)` in the `block statement` in the first code snippet returns a value of `Unit` and the `Unit` datatype doesn't have a function called `toChar`? I am having a hard time figuring out when something returns `Unit` in a `block statement` in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `<fn>()` -- function call operator has higher priority that `<obj>.<field/method>` -- field or method access, so scala thinks you want to call `print(c + i) => Unit` then `Unit.toChar`

Comment: Ohh that makes complete sense. It was stupid of me not to realize that... I guess I was so stuck up in trying to play around with the syntax :). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `print` function returns `Unit`, so:

```
print(c + i).toChar
```

is trying to find a `toChar` method for `Unit` (which doesn't exist).

You need to do this *inside* the print:

```
print((c + i).toChar)
# equivalently 
print(c + i toChar)
```

Comment: What is the significance of doing it inside of the parentheses? Like does it make it return a value? I come from a java and C++ background and some things in Scala I can't make sense of...

Comment: It's *exactly* the same as in Java and C++. In the first case, you call `toChar` on the return value of `print` (which returns `Unit`, which is basically the value that denotes the absence of a meaningful return value … IOW, in Java, `print` would be a `void` method that doesn't return anything at all, but in Scala, every method returns something, so `print` returns something that says "I'm not returning something"). In the second case, you call `toChar` on the result of `c + i` and then `print` the return value of `toChar`. That's not specific to Scala, that's how it works in all languages.

Comment: `(c + i).toChar` is not the same as `c + i toChar`

Comment: @sschaef isn't it? Please can you give an example where they are different?

Comment: I was wrong, it is the same. I did look at it in the wrong way.